# LINQ Sum Syntax

Tags: c#, linq

I'm looking to do a simple sum of a column. The SQL would be:

```sql
Select sum(x1.On_Hand_Qty)
From Material_Location x1
Where x1.Material = '3171784-18'
```

In LINQ I tried:

```
var results = (from x1 in Material_Locations
                where x1.Material == "3171784-18"
                select new {x1.On_Hand_Qty}).Sum();
```

but got this error:

> `'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'` does not contain a
> definition for `'Sum'` and the best extension method overload
> `'System.Linq.Queryable.Sum(System.Linq.IQueryable<int>)'` has some
> invalid arguments
>
> Instance argument: cannot convert from
> `'System.Linq.IQueryable<AnonymousType#1>'` to
> `'System.Linq.IQueryable<int>'`

I tried this:

```
var results = from x1 in Material_Locations
                where x1.Material == "3171784-18"
                select new {x1.On_Hand_Qty.Sum()};
```

and got this error:

> Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must
> be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

`Material_Location.On_Hand_Qty` is a double in the SQL Server.

I'm running out of syntax. There must be a cast I'm missing or something like that. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do not project an anonymous object. Just:

```
var results = (from x1 in Material_Locations
               where x1.Material == "3171784-18"
               select x1.On_Hand_Qty).Sum();
```

When you project the anonymous object (`new {..}`) and then do the `Sum` there is no way for the compiler to sum the items - because the items are not numeric values but objects. And those objects do not override the `+` operator and cannot implicitly be casted to numeric values.

The second version, where you try `x1.On_Hand_Qty.Sum()` won't work as, like you said, `On_Hand_Qty` is a `double` and not an `IEnumerable<T>` which has the `Sum` extension method.

Answer (score 2):

Or you can use:

```
var results = Material_Locations
   .Where(q => q.Material == "3171784-18")
   .Sum(q => q.On_Hand_Qty)
```